# How to redirect js file with Javascript based on referer

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a website `mydomain.com`

I want,

- If visitor mydomain.com come from images.google.com then call `otherdomain.com/file1.js`
- If visitor come from another domain, then call `otherdomain.com/file2.js`

What sort of script should I be using on my domain to do this?mydomain.com

Answer (score 1):

The only option you've got is to use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer); but it is not reliable or trustworthy.

When available, `document.referrer` will give you the come-from URI as a string; if it's not available it'll be empty (`""`).

```
<script>
    if (document.referrer.indexOf('http://images.google.com/') === 0) {
        document.write('<script src="http://otherdomain.com/file1.js"><\/script>');
    } else {
        document.write('<script src="http://otherdomain.com/file2.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And now we look at the syntax highlighting and fix the quote issue. :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Indeed we do ;)

Comment: It will be good to check if `document.referer` exists too, because it can be undefined

Comment: @antyrat: In what browser/ situation? [All](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95229140) the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer) say it'll be an empty string?